# ipad starts in wrong orientation, but Statusbar is right?

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

if I start my App from landscape orientation, the LaunchScreen is in landscape too. But after the default image loading screen.... the App is in portrait but the statusbar is in landscape?!?! very freaky?!

Comment: Have you set window.rootViewController or not? (In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method)

Comment: Yes I have but its still wrong

Comment: In info.plist, supported orientations are LandscapeRight and LandscapeLeft only. Also check with the initialOrientation property. If they are not setup, then please do that.

Comment: I fixed it with this hack in appdelegate applicationdidfinished  :-(                               UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [_sbvc presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [_sbvc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
            });
            
        }];